# Excel Function - Copying

Tags: excel, vba, formula, cell

So for example if I have a spreadsheet with BYM01 in a cell and have about 8/10 blank under it then BYM02, how would I be able to copy the BYM01 automatically into the blank spaces under it until it hits BYM02 after which it copies that to the cells under it.

Comment: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/02/fill-blanks-excel/

Comment: Can the values `BYM01`, `BYM02`, … be determined by another column?